# how do i sum any elements in the list of lists and equal to 5 in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I‘m new to learn the Prolog. I want to fulfill the below predicate.

```
equalto5([[1,'a'],[3,'b'],[2,'b'],[1,'b'],[4,'c']], X) --input
```

remove all the duplicated numbers by the first element in the list of lists, Don't remove the duplicated letters by the second element.

like this: `equalto5([[1,'a'],[3,'b'],[2,'b'],[4,'c']], X)`

then find all possible results that equal 5 based on the first element in the list of lists

```
X =[1,4]; [2,3].
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Are there any specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
equalto5(List, X) :-
    findall(Num, member([Num, _], List), Ns_dupes),   % numbers from nested lists.
    sort(Ns_dupes, Ns),    % sort/2 also deduplicates.
    member(N1, Ns),        % look for N1 from the numbers ...
    member(N2, Ns),        % and N2 ...
    dif(N1, N2),           % which are different ...
    5 is N1 + N2,          % and sum to 5.
    X = [N1, N2].
```